# Is there any tool that supports checkpoint based memory usage profiling for C++

Tags: c++, windows, linux, memory-profiling, checkpoint

I am working on a network based application. I want to see the memory usage between different stages of my application, like memory usage between initialization and release or memory usage between send and receive. I have googled and try to find a solution but no post that exactly matches my requirements.

Please, you guys, can suggest any tool or process that can help me to perform **checkpoint based** memory profiling both in Linux and Windows platform.

Thanks in advance

---

The following code

```
_CrtMemState memState1;
_CrtMemCheckpoint(&memState1);

char *p = new char[100];
p = new char[100];
p = new char[100];
p = new char[100];
p = new char[100];

_CrtMemState memState2;
_CrtMemCheckpoint(&memState2);
_CrtMemState memStateDiff;
_CrtMemDifference(&memStateDiff, &memState1, &memState2);
_CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memStateDiff);'
```

gives me output

```
0 bytes in 0 Free Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Normal Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 CRT Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Ignore Blocks.
0 bytes in 0 Client Blocks.
Largest number used: 0 bytes.
Total allocations: 0 bytes.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: No post that *exactly* matches your requirements? Anything remotely close? Memory management internals is very vendors-specific, and as such you're not going to get a canned works-on-windows-and-linux answer.

Comment: Are you actually compiling for debug mode?  You need to define  _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC and rebuild otherwise you aren't using the malloc/free that generates the stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkpoint based memory usage is built in to the debug CRT libraries in Visual C++.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1(v=vs.80).aspx